# Is Morphia based on Java driver for MongoDb and can it work if domain model is scala?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

Is it based on [mongoDb java driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) ?

Can I use it when the domain model is scala program in version 1.2.2RC1+ of play framework?

Please note that questions that may have been answered before may not be relevant to play framework version 1.2.2RC1+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphia does run on top of/uses the mongodb java driver. All java ORM solutions do. I don't see why it would be a problem to run it in Scala. I have no experience with the "play framework".

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a  high level Java client for MongoDB, Give Kundera (https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera) a try. It’s a JPA based client library for Cassandra, Hbase and MongoDB. There is a pretty good example here: https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-started